# iphone IOS Anyway to get Added Control in ToolBar to come to front

Tags: iphone, uitoolbar, badge

This is a bit of a hack, but trying to get a badge on a toolbaritem.  Almost there, but it appears in the back, tried normal methods to get to front with no luck.

[image: Behind a toolbar]

```
deletedCountBadge = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:@"0"];
deletedCountBadge.frame = CGRectMake(100,10,25,25);

UIView *view = (UIView *)[bottomToolBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
[view addSubview:deletedCountBadge];
```

Comment: did you try [view bringSubviewToFront:deletedCountBadge];?

Comment: My inclination is to add the badge to the toolbar and then call `[toolbar:bringSubviewToFront:badge]`. Not sure if you've tried that already though.

Comment: [bottomToolBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] looks like toolbar background view, how about adding deleteCountBadge to bottomToolBar direct: [bottomToolBar addSubview: deletedCountBadge]

Comment: The bring to font does not work.  I wanted the badge to be "on top of"  the left most button.  Have tried where view is from objectAtIndex:1 with same result.  If I addSubview, then the badge has it's own space and is not on top of the button.  Will probably have to make a custom button and put the badge in it and then add to toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work with a couple of different pointers on the net.

1) If you are moving the toolbar around at all (.frame=) make sure to set the items after the layout

2) Can use negative spacing items to get it to show up where you want.

[image]

```
UIBarButtonItem *deleteBadge = [BarButtonItemBadge barButtonItemBadge:@"1" insideColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

UIBarButtonItem *negativeSeperator = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
negativeSeperator.width = -30;

[bottomToolBarDictionaryButtonItems addObject:deleteBadge];
[bottomToolBarDictionaryButtonItems addObject:negativeSeperator];

// after any layout, of tool bar

[bottomToolBar setItems:bottomToolBarDictionaryButtonItems];
```